# Assign an element to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Javascript object following the Module Pattern

```
var foo = (function() {
     var obj = (function() {
         var $button = $('#myButton');

         var init = function() {
            $button.hide();
         };

         return {
            init: init
         };
     })();

    return { obj: obj };
})();
```

If I call `foo.obj.init()`, the button should be hidden, and this does not occur.

I saw different questions here about the assignment of an element to a variable, but I think that the problem is with the object. Can't I access a private variable from a public method?

Comment: The obvious question is whether the DOM was loaded at the time you ran this method.

Comment: And if you loaded jQuery.

Comment: I loaded jQuery, and the `init`is called when the document is ready.

Comment: I think the best answer might be to teach you to debug javascript code. use `console.log` method and the `debugger;` statement to see what is going on, when your code is executed. Your jquery object might be simply empty

Comment: try to put `debugger;` right after `var $button` line and see in dev tools what is contained in your $button variable

Comment: Something else is up - it works here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/xbgweP. Any errors in your JS console?

Comment: I put a `debugger;` and we have a jQuery element.....

Comment: and no errors @PaulRoub

Comment: and what does your jquery element contain? could you post here what exactly you see in the dev tools?

Comment: jquery element can be empty, that is contain 0 dom objects

Comment: `[context: document, selector: "#myButton", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…]`

Comment: I updated the code.....there's an object inside another...

Comment: try to put `console.log($button.length)` in place of the `debugger;` or right before it

Comment: the `$button` is assigned when your script is loaded (because `foo` is created immediately which then creates `obj` immediately), you need to wait to get the button until the document is ready.

Comment: It works fine on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8gj6aodv/1/

Comment: @prodigitalson got the point! That was the problem....I was instatiating the object.....Isn't there a way to create the object just after the document is ready?

Comment: Do it as part of `init`... you can just declare the var in order to isolate the scope, and then modify it to actually set the button as part of `init`.

Comment: Also , for those of you saying it works in the fiddle... it does because you were using `onLoad` or `onReady`... if you change that to `no wrap - body` or `no wrap - head` it will not (well body could depending on where in the body the script is placed and what elements are loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

> Do it as part of init... you can just declare the var in order to isolate the scope, and then modify it to actually set the button as part of init

Example:

```
var foo = (function() {
     var obj = (function() {
         var $button; //$('#myButton');

         var init = function() {
            if (typeof $button === 'undefined') {
                // i would probably make the selector an argument to `init`
                // if i were you.
                $button = $('#myButton');
            }
            $button.hide();
         };

         return {
            init: init
         };
     })();

    return { obj: obj };
})();
```